# RewriteRule for friendlier URLs

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a site that has a news section in a subfolder which I have been adding to manually.

`www.example.com/subfolder/news-and-views/name-of-article.php`

I recently made a rather simplistic CRUD feature to make adding these articles easier.

I have:

1. `www.example.com/subfolder/news-and-views/index.php` - This displays all articles
2. `www.example.com/subfolder/news-and-views/article.php` - This takes an Id parameter from a `$_GET` request

The url I end up with when I view an article is:

`www.example.com/subfolder/news-and-views/article.php?Id=name-of-article`

I did some reading and used http://htaccess.mwl.be/ to test a RewriteRule

The rule is: `RewriteRule /news-and-views/(.+) /news-and-views/article.php?Id=$1.php [L]`

However when I go to `news-and-vies/` (the index page) my CSS is stripped out and nothing is displayed as my paths are changed.

Also it seems to go to article.phpid?= without passing anything, rather than just using the actual index page.

To set paths I use a variable called `$path2root` which is the number of directories to the root.
E.g `$path2root = "../../";`

So: I'd have `include $path2root . "includes/head.php"`

Is my RewriteRule interferring with this variable?

**My .htaccess file**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /news-and-views/(.+) /news-and-views/article.php?Id=$1.php [L]
```

**My file structure**

```
/ .htaccess at this level (root)
--/ subfolder
----/ news-and-views
------/ index of news and views
```

Comment: Where is this `.htaccess` file located? What has happened to `/subfolder` in the _substitution_ string? Please include your entire `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Okay, I'll add extra detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule /news-and-views/(.+) /news-and-views/article.php?Id=$1.php [L]
> ```

As mentioned in my comment, you appear to have omitted the `/subfolder`, so I'm not sure how this rewrites successfully at all? You also need to be careful of rewriting existing files (eg. `index.php` and `article.php` and CSS?) and creating a rewrite loop.

Try something like the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(subfolder/news-and-views)/(.+) /$1/article.php?Id=$2.php [L]
```